# Bootstrap 4 cards: remove blank space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">


  <div class="card bg-light col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-header col-6 border">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-6 border">
        <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border">
        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card bg-light col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-header col-6 border">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-6 border">
        <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border">
        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card bg-light col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-header col-6 border">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-6 border">
        <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border">
        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card bg-light col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-header col-6 border">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-6 border">
        <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border">
        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's a lot of empty space in card. I need it as:
[image]

Comment: `The content (1234567899) will always be of 10 digits that too without any space between` (I was unable to edit, so commented here)

Comment: What's your problem with achieving this? It seems like a simple CSS change to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by adding `class="p-0 my-auto"` to remove `padding` and to center vertical. Below is the working snippet for the same

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-body.col-6 {
  background: red
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  .img-container {
    height: 63px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  .img-container {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card bg-light col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card-header col-6 border p-0">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-container" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-6 border p-0 ">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">1234567899</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card bg-light col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card-header col-6 border p-0">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-container" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-6 border p-0 ">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">1234567899</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card bg-light col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card-header col-6 border p-0">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-container" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-6 border p-0  ">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">1234567899</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Solution-2: Answered as per the question in the comment.Giving fixed height to `col`. Below is the solution for the same

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-body.col-6 {
  background: red
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}

.col-6 {
  height:65px;
}
.img-fluid {
 height:100%!important;
}
.card-header.col-6{
     background: black
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card bg-light col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card-header col-6 border p-0 text-center">
          
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
         
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-6 border p-0 ">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">1234567899</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card bg-light col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card-header col-6 border p-0 text-center">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-6 border p-0 ">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">1234567899</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card bg-light col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card-header col-6 border p-0 text-center">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-6 border p-0  ">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">1234567899</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please see the image in the question, I want like that. In your answer, it's just coming to the center

Comment: I don't want space above and below the text (1234567899)!

Comment: @orever check it now

Comment: This time it worked, but the image is being stretched!

Comment: `object-fit: cover;` will scale your image according to the width of container. If there is no requirement to fill the complete image in the `col` you can give fixed height to `col` as per your requirement. Hope your doubts are cleared. Please accept my answer if you feel that my answer helped you. Happy coding

Comment: @orever updated both the solutions. Choose the one according to your requirement

Comment: The button section in your answer (2nd) works as expected for me but here, (https://jsfiddle.net/gh1snp80/) it doesn't. Why so?

Comment: you need to remove  `<h5 class="card-title">` whic was wrapped for button

Comment: Got it, we use `.col-md-3` so that we can have 4 columns in a row. Right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Please up-vote my answer if you feel that was helpful

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gh1snp80/ run the script in fullscreen, here it will only have 3 columns in a row and fourth in another line. How to adjust them?

Comment: It's because you have added margin classes to `col-md-3` `div`

Comment: So, how can I achieve that, I need space between two columns and space between starting and ending...

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.card-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="row">


  <div class="card bg-light col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 p-0 border">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="col p-0 border text-center">
        <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-12 p-0 border">
        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="card bg-light col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 p-0 border">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="col p-0 border text-center">
        <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-12 p-0 border">
        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="card bg-light col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 p-0 border">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="col p-0 border text-center">
        <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-12 p-0 border">
        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="card bg-light col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 p-0 border">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="col p-0 border text-center">
        <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-12 p-0 border">
        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes you did, so that I can try on my server (original codes)

Comment: I have to remove extra space in the column.  if this not good your requirement according. so Please explain to me what excites problem

Comment: What you did to remove extra space..?

Comment: I have added  bootstrap class `p-0` in column

Comment: Yes, see my image the div is just taking that much space the text required!

Comment: if you want the text in the center you can use this CSS `.col.p-0.border.text-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}`

Comment: Still, on small screens (mobile) it has space!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <section class="test">
     <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3 ">
           <div class="card bg-light">
              <div class="card-body p-0">
                 <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 border">
                      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 border px-3 pt-2">
                      <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3 ">
           <div class="card bg-light">
              <div class="card-body p-0">
                 <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 border">
                      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 border px-3 pt-2">
                      <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3">
           <div class="card bg-light">
              <div class="card-body p-0">
                 <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 border">
                      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 border px-3 pt-2">
                      <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3 ">
           <div class="card bg-light">
              <div class="card-body p-0">
                 <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 border">
                      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/19/08/39/mobile-phone-1917737__340.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 border px-3 pt-2">
                      <h5 class="card-title">1234567899</h5>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></h5>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
```